# CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY in JPA2 refresh cache

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, ehcache

I am using CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY in JPA2 in a WebLogic Server Version: 12.1.2.0.0 and its working fine, I've just inserted a new record in the DB using PL/SQL Developer and I want to refresh the cache to see the new record inserted.... I've restarted the server but it does not worked ....
What should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY` is a [read-through cache](http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-cache-synchronization-strategies/) and entities are cached upon loading.

To insert new cache entries, you'd have to select them using a [batch processor](http://vladmihalcea.com/scheduled-jobs-best-practices/).